# Adding XML feedback functionality to website

Tags: php, xml, web, rss

Few years back I made a university website using PHP where notices are uploaded and students can see it.Now they want me to develop an android application which I can use to get notices from the website using XML parsing.

That is,the website should have dual functionality -It can be accessed by a PC (like normally we do) as well as it can be accessed by the app.I can develop the android app.That part is OK.But the problems are on the source-side(server-side).I have following questions :-

1)Do I have to buy a separate url for xml responses and share the old database?

2)If not , then how can I add XML feed functionality and how will I identify the client whether it is a PC or the app(a guidance).

The website screenshot
[image]

Any good tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to buy a separate url for xml responses

No.

> and share the old database?

Presumably you *want* to use the same database. If you want different content (as well as difference presentation of that content) then you should have it on different URLs.

> If not , then how can I add XML feed functionality

Pick your favourite PHP XML library.

> and how will I identify the client whether it is a PC or the app(a guidance).

Don't try to identify what the client is. Identify what sort of data it wants. Use [the HTTP Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).